# Django User Profile Form Empty

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

i know their is already a lot of post about that but i tried a lot of solutions and i cannot display my form !

I want to do something really simple (i'm a Django beginner), i create a specific UserProfile to extend the basic one, and i want to let the user edit it :

Here is my model :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    cc = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user.email)

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = UserProfile
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = kwargs['instance']

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Here is my view method :

```
@login_required
def accountform(request):
    data = {}
    data.update(csrf(request))
    user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
    data['form'] = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile)
    print user_profile
    return render(request, 'accountform.html', data)
```

Here is my template :

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

when i display the from i just see the submit button...

Comment: Everything looks ok, have you missed anything while posting?

Comment: No i haven't miss anything, i'm stuck on this now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `meta` inner class should be capitalized - `Meta`

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:  # not meta
        model = UserProfile
```